# Sublime Text: can not download with sync-setting package due to randomly changed "ignored_packages" list

Tags: sublimetext3

I am trying to download/install some 50+ packages with ["Sync Settings"](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Sync%20Settings) package. So, I do Preferences > Packages Settings > Sync Settings > Settings - and my User file's contents are like below.

```
{
  /**
    * This token allow to plugin do:
    * - Create a Gist
    * - Download a Gist
    * - Upload a Gist
    * - Delete a Gist
   */
  "access_token": "54564545454545646465456+4651465",

  /**
   * Gist identifier for upload your configuration
   */
  "gist_id": "hd4554dsg45g5d4gjjmd54",

  /**
   * Download automagically the new version on ST startup
   */
  "auto_upgrade": false
}
```

But it fails, giving me the below error pop-up

**It appears a package is trying to ignore itself, causing a loop.
    Please resolve by removing the offending ignored_packages setting.**

And then when I navigate to Preference > Settings I see the below

```
{
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ]
}
```

I have looked through [this issue](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/2132), but it did not resolve my problem.

My system settings
Ubuntu - 18.04
Sublime Text - version 3.2 Build 3200

Answer (score 2):

This just happened to me, but it seemed to resolve itself upon retrying.  I just dismissed the warnings as they popped up and then let it finish downloading all of my packages.  Then, I restarted Sublime (not sure if this was necessary) and downloaded the settings once more (not sure if this was necessary either).  The second time, there were no errors.

Comment: Also worked for me upon restarting Sublime and retrying.